# Excel save as on Run

Tags: vba, excel, save

In Excel, after writing a VBA script, I would like Excel to save the file before running it.

It is common on most of the programming tools.
While testing a program, it may crash and my program may not be saved but if it saves before each run, I won't have this problem anymore.

I know there is a automatically save option in Excel but is there another alternative ?

Comment: Maybe `ThisWorkbook.Save`  ...?

Comment: If it's not a VBA solution you're looking for, then maybe reducing the time between autosaves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

at the beginning of your macro

Comment: You should try to avoid `active` and `selection`, it is a very common cause of bugs, especially if you have multiple workbooks open. In general it's best to avoid `Active(Workbook/Sheet/Cell)` and the `.Select/.Activate` method or `.Selection` property. There are of course cases where it is unavoidable but this isn't one of them.

Comment: Thank you for the VBA alternative, I was wondering if there was an option in Excel, I search for it but without success.